# Move fetch req and update core data to model

Tags: core-data, swiftui

How to move fetch request and update value from core data into model?

I have core data, let's say login data (userToken, isLogin and userType). I need to show and update this data in 2 view. So I need to create update, save and fetch request multiple times. Maybe in login view and profile view.

Is it possible to use model for update, save, delete and fetch request from my core data?

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
  @State var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool = true
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
  @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
  private var userData: FetchedResults<LoginData>
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color.green
      Button(action: {
        setLogin()
      }){
        Text("Login Screen")
          .foregroundColor(Color.black)
      }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Hidden Title")
    .navigationBarHidden(self.isNavigationBarHidden)
    .onAppear {
      self.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
  }
  
  private func saveContext() {
    do {
      try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
      let error = error as NSError
      fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
    }
  }
  
  private func setLogin(){
    let newUser = LoginData(context: viewContext)
    newUser.isLogin = true
    newUser.userToken = "JWT_TOKEN"
    
    saveContext()
  }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    LoginView()
  }
}
```

I want to put this in my model

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
private var userData: FetchedResults<LoginData>

private func saveContext() {
  do {
    try viewContext.save()
  } catch {
    let error = error as NSError
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
  }
}
  
private func setLogin(){
  let newUser = LoginData(context: viewContext)
  newUser.isLogin = true
  newUser.userToken = "JWT_TOKEN"
   
  saveContext()
}
```

I already try like this.

```
import SwiftUI

class UserDataModel: ObservableObject {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
  @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
  var loginData: FetchedResults<LoginData>
  
  func saveContext() {
    do {
      try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
      let error = error as NSError
      fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
    }
  }
  
  func setLogin(){
    let newUser = LoginData(context: viewContext)
    newUser.isLogin = true
    newUser.userToken = "JWT_TOKEN"
    
    saveContext()
  }
  
  func setLogout(){
    viewContext.delete(loginData[0])
    saveContext()
  }
}
```

But its show me error.

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unresolved error Foundation._GenericObjCError.nilError
```

Comment: CoreData objects is-a model level reference type objects, you can move them in run-time by reference anywhere and anyhow.

Comment: I already update my question.

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but it feels like you have two different Managed Object Contexts, even though both are generated from the same environment. Have you tried to pass the managed object to the model from the view? Or just the appropriate data to the model, and let it create and save the MO?

Answer (score 1):

To make things a little easier, you can store a persistent container within your `ObservableObject`.

```swift
class Publisher: ObservableObject {
    static let shared: Publisher = Publisher()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    lazy var context = container.viewContext

    @Published var isLoading: Bool = false

    init() {
        self.container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataModelName")
    
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then set it as the `managedObjectContext` using the `environment` view modifier:
*Try to set this as early as possible within your view hierarchy so it will be accessible to the remaining views*

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject // or @ObservedObject
    var publisher: Publisher = .shared

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
        // set `managedObjectContext` here
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, publisher.context)
    }
}
```

You should then have access to the view context across multiple views:

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    private var viewContext // Use the environment object `managedObjectContext`
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    private var objects: FetchedResults<Object>

    var body: some View {
        Text(“Hello World!”)
    }

    private func saveContext() {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let error = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
        }
    }

    private func saveObject() {
        let object = Object(context: viewContext)
        saveContext()
    }
}
```

And, also, have access within your `ObservableObject` class:

```swift
extension Publisher {
    /// Function used to update the current state of the app.
    func update(_ perform: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            isLoading = true
            perform?()
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
    func saveContext() {
        update { [self] in
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let error = error as NSError
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    func save(object: Object) {
        context.insert(object)
        saveContext()
    }
    func delete(object: Object) {
        context.delete(object)
        saveContext()
    }
}
```